# How to force iSCSI disk refresh/rescan

Tags: iscsi, windows-cluster, windows-server-2022

I have a 3 node Windows 2022 cluster that is using iSCSI attached volumes.  When I reboot the servers I get a ton of MPIO errors and it takes forever to see the disks.  When they are seen in Disk Management, I cannot see all the information I usually see when viewing these disks like the Partition and Volume names.  All I see are the disks themselves as if they were empty.  Refreshing and/or Rescanning from Disk Management does nothing.  Is there a way to reset the iSCSI controllers so I can force Windows to reread and mount the disks again?  Right now I'm rebooting, but it's taking forever for the server to come back up to a state where I can remote to it again.